# Are there any heavy tailed distributions available for GAMM?

Tags: r, distributions, generalized-additive-model, qq-plot, heavy-tailed

I have a gamm that looks to be heavy tailed according to the qqplot so I'd like to account for this. According to [this page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/family.mgcv.html) things like scaled t distributions for heavy tailed data are only available for GAM or BAM.

[image]

Here's my model if it helps:

```
m1<-
  gamm(
    y ~ s(day_of_year, k = 100) + s(deaths, k = 100) +
      s(Month, bs = 'cc', k = 12) + indicator + Year,
    data = mydata,
    method = "REML",
    correlation = corAR1()
  )
```

Comment: You could use `bam()` and hand optimise the AR(1) parameter

Comment: Thank you, I came across this link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/itsadug/vignettes/acf.html which suggests I run a model without the autocorrelation and use that to supply the value of Rho to the model with autocorrelation. Is that what you mean by hand optimising?

Comment: That's one way to do it; the other is to fit models over the range of rho values you want to try and see which gives the lowest REML score for example.